# Is this sentence missing the relative pronoun "that"?

Tags: word-usage, relative-clauses, relative-pronouns, parsing, optional-that

> He will support whichever candidate wins. ([source](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/whichever))

This sentence strikes me as missing a relative pronoun. I thought it should read:

> He will support whichever candidate **that** wins.

Per relative pronoun rules, I thought "that" can be left out when it is the *object* of a relative clause, e.g. "Take whichever book you want.", not when it is the *subject*.

In order to parse the first sentence, I am trying to think of an equivalent for the *adjective* **whichever**. Dictionaries have "no matter which", but this substitution seems to work with such sentences as

> Whichever (No matter which) job you take, starting out will be hard.

But not with the sentence at issue. So how should I understand the structure of that first sentence? Am I correct in saying it is missing "that"? What would be a working multi-word equivalent for **whichever** (so that I can better parse such sentences)?

Comment: Regardless of what's missing or not missing in this sentence, I'd recommend using the relative pronoun **who** instead of **that** when referring to people.

Answer (score 1):

The original sentence, "He will support whichever candidate wins", is correct. The clause "whichever candidate wins" is a free relative clause generated by the relative determiner "whichever".

The sentence "He will support whichever candidate that wins" is incorrect, because an *extra* relative pronoun has been inserted where there's no place for it.

Answer (score 0):

"Which" is a relative pronoun: "He will support the candidate which wins". Not the most grammatical choice in this context, but clearly acting as a relative pronoun. "Whichever" retains the relativizer status. See, for instance http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/pronouns/relative-pronoun.html  We're just putting the relative pronoun before the noun, rather than between the noun and the verb. So the problem with a multi-word equivalent is that it would be hard to give one without reordering the words: "He will support **whichever** candidate wins." is equivalent to "He will support **the** candidate **who** wins.

Comment: I get your point, but I don't know if I am convinced. My reservation is that the usage of "whichever" in the sentence at issue is not pronominal but adjectival. In "Take whichever you like better", _whichever_ is pronominal.